# Make one variable double the value of the other with SASS

Tags: sass

Im using SASS. I need on value to be double another value so the logic is this:

```
.one {
 padding: 'value';
}
.two {
 padding: 'value times 2';
}
```

So it could be this:

```
.one {
 padding: 2px;
}
.two {
 padding: 4px;
}
```

Or this:

```
.one {
 padding: 10px;
}
.two {
 padding: 20px;
}
```

How can I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a value you can reuse, you need a variable.

```
$my-padding: 1em;
.one {
    padding: $my-padding;
}
.two {
    padding: $my-padding * 2;
}
```